# Tableau-Quick Table calculations not working

Tags: tableau-api

In columns, I have "Category" in columns and in Rows, I have Sum(Sales). I added a quick table calculation for percent of total. Y axis vales changed  to percentages however numbers on top of the bars are not changing into percentages. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drag the table calculation, the pill on the Rows shelf, to the Label shelf.

Ctrl-drag from Rows and the calculation will match exactly that on the Rows, including any advanced settings.

I guess you just have a standard SUM([Sales]) currently on the label shelf.